# A better way to indicate links for texts in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, hyperlink, border, anchor

I made style for `a` tag in my wordpress as a bottom-dotted border, so that I can tell users there's a clickable link.

[image: bottom-dotted border for links]

However, in Wordpress, an image in post is inside `a` tag, which means that a border would show in the bottom of an image. This can't be changed in edit mode since the `p` which encloses `a` is automatically generated.

[image: bottom-dotted border in images]

```
<p>
  <a href="">
    <img src="">
  </a>
</p>
```

Is there a better way to deal with this? Maybe it's Javascript code to take the dotted border off from `a`, but I wonder if there's a better way.

Comment: I tried to add [this](http://jsbin.com/lojome/edit?js,output), which I saw on Stack Overflow, but it failed. What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need Javascript because you want to search for `a` tags which are parent to `img` tag and in CSS, there are no parent selectors.

Comment: Any idea on Javascript code to filter `.entry-content p a img`?